# Is there a way to see a history of function calls in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

Working on a project that keeps crashing. No errors and showing up, my memory monitor tells me that everything is normal and as far as I can see there is nothing aberrant in my code it just stops working, freezes. **Is there a way to see a history in visual studio of function calls so I can ascertain accurately the last thing my program does before it breaks?**

Thanks!

Comment: Your process crashes or freezes?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code?

Answer (score 5):

menu bar -> DEbug -> Windows -> Call Stack

Comment: Is this really useful? Call stack in VS only shows something when there is a breakpoint.